# Matching using Random Forest

Tags: r, matching, random-forest

As a newbie in the random forest world, I have a (basic) question. Following Zhao, Su, Tingting, and Fan (2016), I'm trying to do the following procedure:

```
For b = 1, ..., B, do

   Using all data, grow a tree with treatment as output and all other covariates as inputs.

   Compute % of treated observations s_i for the terminal node to which i belongs.

   Update S_i = S_i + s_i

end

prop_score = S_i / B
```

To run this algorithm, I use `randomForest` function:

```
 model1 = randomForest(treatment ~ ., data = dataset, keep.forest = T, ntree = 100, na.action = na.omit)
```

That being said, could you let me know how to obtain the information about where each *i* belongs to certain terminal node? Also, any recommended package for handling pretty large data? `randomForest` freezes unless I limited the number of trees to a small number.

Comment: you can use `do.trace` argument to give a little output during model training.  For example, `do.trace=10` will print a summary of OOB error every 10 trees. That might help you gauge progress while training on very large datasets.

Comment: Isn't it so with random forests that each _i_ may belong, not to a single, but to several terminal nodes.

Comment: Yes, Heikki. That's why S_i / B will be considered as the propensity score for the individual *i*.